# How to remove rules message when other event is triggered

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element

How to remove rules message when other event is triggered

```
return {
          'first_name': [
            {
              required: !this.form.gender,
              message: this.form.gender ? '' : Field can not be empty',
              trigger: 'blur',
            }
          ],
          'last_name': [
            {
              required: !this.form.gender,
              message: 'Field can not be empty',
              trigger: 'blur',
            }
          ]
      }
```

If gender is true then messge should be blank how can i achieve this. What currently is working it remove the required asterisk but did not remove message since it will only work when blur trigger. I don't want either it should remove message to if gender is true please guide thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Your first example of "first_name" seems to work like what you are describing you want done?

Comment: Just want to update the message if i have flag 1 of gender button then it should says Field can not be empty else it should be blank and it should work based on button click